# Decimal field not being deserialized while integer value works fine

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization

Sample Xml:

```
<TestXML>
   <TestDecimal attr1="Required" attr2="false">0.34</TestDecimal>
   <TestInteger attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestInteger>
</TestXML>
```

Class Definitions:

```
public class TestXML {
   public DecimalValue TestDecimal;
   public IntegerValue TestInteger;
}

public class IntegerValue {
   [XmlText]
   public int value {get; set;}
   [XmlAnyAttribute]
   public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes {get; set;}
}
public class DecimalValue {
   [XmlText]
   public decimal value {get; set;}
   [XmlAnyAttribute]
   public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes {get; set;}
}
```

Code to deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.xml", FileMode.Open)) {
   TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

In testing this it comes back with the integer value but not the decimal value:

```
myxml
   TestDecimal
      value |  0
      XAttributes  {string[2]}
         [0] Name="attr1", Value="Required"
         [1] Name="attr2", Value="false"
   TestInteger
      value |  25
      XAttributes  {string[3]}
         [0] Name="attr1", Value="MyAttr"
         [1] Name="attr2", Value="1"
         [2] Name="DateAdded", Value=""
```

Is there something about deserializing decimals that would cause it come back as 0?  With the primitive type of decimal the decimal value comes back fine.

Comment: I have never seen `DecimalValue`, `IntegerValue` class before. Try to change to decimal and see the results

Comment: Those class objects are used to hold the attributes which is required.  The primitive type works but can't use for attributes.

Comment: Have you tried serializing to see if that works?  In other words, given an in-memory object, can you create an XML file with the correct content?

Comment: I have checked at my end, and it is deserializing correctly, Problem seems to be at the verification/serilization step.

Comment: By replacing "." By "," what's the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be doing something differently in your actual code than what you are showing here. Your code does not compile as posted - specifically class definitions don't have () after their names in C#.

This works for me as expected (the decimal value gets deserialized correctly):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{

    public class TestXML
    {
        public DecimalValue TestDecimal;
        public IntegerValue TestInteger;
    }

    public class IntegerValue
    {
        [XmlText]
        public int value {get; set;}
        [XmlAnyAttribute]
        public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes {get; set;}
    }

    public class DecimalValue
    {
        [XmlText]
        public decimal value {get; set;}
        [XmlAnyAttribute]
        public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes {get; set;}
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Test()
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.xml", FileMode.Open)) 
            {
                TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }
    }
}
```

This is with a local test.xml file copied to the bin directory containing this data:

```
<TestXML>
    <TestDecimal attr1="Required" attr2="false">0.34</TestDecimal>
    <TestInteger attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestInteger>
</TestXML>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my real problem was with Visual Studio not compiling my real code correctly.  Did a clean solution and then it started working correctly.